# Бот не реагирует на нажатие inline кнопки Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу бота с помощью библиотеки aiogram.  Диалог формируется с помощью FSM.

суть такова: бот спрашивает пользователя название города, он вводит, я обращаюсь к API,  и так как в результатах чаще всего несколько вариантов, я формирую инлайн кнопки с названиями. Пользователь нажимает нужную кнопку, опрос продолжается.
Но всё спотыкается на нажатии инлайн кнопки. (я так подозреваю что неправильно регистрировал хендлеры)
код

```
class HotelOrder(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_city_name_h = State()
    waiting_for_city_answer_h = State()
    waiting_for_hotel_number_h = State()
    waiting_for_photo_number_h = State()
    waiting_for_history_saving_h = State()


async def hotels_start(message: types.Message):
    message_text = f'введите название города'
    await message.answer(message_text)
    await HotelOrder.waiting_for_city_name_h.set()
    logger.info('старт прошёл')


async def hotels_buttons(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    logger.info('hotels_buttons вызвано')
    loc = make_locations_list(message=message)
    if not loc or len(loc) <1:
        await message.answer("Ничего не найдено, повторите запрос.")
        return
    elif loc.get('bad_request'):
        await message.answer('сервер недоступен')
        return
    else:

        city_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        for loc_name, loc_id in loc.items():
            city_keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                text = loc_name,
                callback_data=f'code{loc_id}'
            ))
        await message.answer('жми кнопка', reply_markup=city_keyboard)
        await HotelOrder.waiting_for_city_answer_h.set()


async def city_name_chosen(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(city_id=call.data[4:])
    await HotelOrder.next()
    await call.answer("сколько отелей выводить ?:")
    await HotelOrder.waiting_for_hotel_number_h.set()


async def hotel_count_chosen(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    код опущен для краткости

async def photo_count_chosen(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext)
    код опущен для краткости
async def history_chosen(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    код опущен для краткости
    await state.finish()

async def cancel(message: types.Message, state:FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer('Действие отменено', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())


def register_handlers_highprice(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(hotels_start, commands="highprice", state="*")
    dp.register_message_handler(hotels_buttons, state=HotelOrder.waiting_for_city_name_h)
    dp.callback_query_handler(city_name_chosen, state=HotelOrder.waiting_for_city_answer_h)
    dp.register_message_handler(hotel_count_chosen, state=HotelOrder.waiting_for_hotel_number_h)
    dp.register_message_handler(photo_count_chosen, state=HotelOrder.waiting_for_photo_number_h)
    dp.register_message_handler(history_chosen, state=HotelOrder.waiting_for_history_saving_h)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в конце не

```
callback_query_handler
```

а

```
register_callback_query_handler
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!